# Check if the web request addressing ad site

Tags: c#, http

I'm writing a simple HTTP proxy, which will play a role of an adblock. I want it to check the request's url, and tell, whether it's trying, for example, download css styles, or go for an advertisment site. Is there a neat way to do so? Except for skipping the urls, which contains "/ad/", "/ads/" and so on? Because right now my code looks like something like this:

```
    public void ProcessRequest()
    {
        var url = context.Request.RawUrl;

        if (url.Contains("/ad/"))
            return;

        //and some code to get an actual answer
    }
```

Comment: What does your code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: You could use https://filterlists.com/

Comment: @mjwills If the url contains the word "ad", it assumes, that the client wants to download some arvertisment, so it just throws that request away. And if there are no "stop words", it will resend it to upper server and get normal response.